# Lagrange multipliers with scipy.optimize.linprog

Tags: python, scipy, mathematical-optimization

Is it possible to retriev the Lagrange multipliers from [scipy linprog](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.linprog.html) like in Matlab linprog? If so how?

I read the documentation but I didn't find it. There is a `return` parameter call `slack` but I think this is something different because it is only related to the inequality constraint:

> slack: 1D array
>
> The (nominally positive) values of the slack variables, b_ub - A_ub @ x.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not implemented yet. See [How to get Lagrange / lambda multipliers out of 'linprog' optimize subroutine in scipy module ? #11848](https://github.com/scipy/scipy/issues/11848).

Answer (score 2):

Although my question was already answered by Arraval. I found a work around that I want to share, also using `scipy`. `Linprog` hasn't implemented yet but the `minimize` function can return the Lagrange multipliers when utilizing the [`method='trust-constr'`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.minimize-trustconstr.html#optimize-minimize-trustconstr):

[image]

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

Starting from scipy 1.7.0, one can also receive the Lagrangian multipliers (also known as *dual values* or *shadow prices*) by using the [HiGHS dual simplex solver](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/optimize.linprog-highs-ds.html#optimize-linprog-highs-ds):

```py
import numpy as np
from scipy.optimize import linprog

c = -1*np.array([300, 500])
A_ub = np.array([[1, 2], [1, 1], [0, 3]])
b_ub = np.array([170, 150, 180])
A_eq = np.array([[1, 1]])
b_eq = np.array([80])

# solve c'x  s.t.  A_ub*x <= b_ub, A_eq*x == b_eq, x >= 0
result = linprog(c=c, A_ub=A_ub, b_ub=b_ub, method="highs-ds")

# lagrangian multipliers
λ_ineq = result['ineqlin']['marginals']
λ_eq   = result['eqlin']['marginals']
```